# how can i bind columns which is not available in my database in datatable jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I used datatable jquery plugin.i want to bind values to column which is not available in my database.for example I have column name 'Leave Balance' which is calculated by query.i have two more column which is calculated by query.so how can i define column 'Leave Balance' at server side? how can i retrieve it.Please Help me.

I have tried below code at server side.In My code  'Date',LeaveBalance','NumberOfDays' column are calculated by query.so how can i bind it with datatable.

```
<?php
//$path=realpath ('wp-content/plugins/Employee_Time_Tracker/connection.php');
//include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\cosmos\wp-content\plugins\Employee_Time_Tracker\connection.php';

/*get database values*/
$databasename=$_POST['databasename'];
$databaseuser=$_POST['databaseuser'];
$databasehost=$_POST['databasehost'];
$databasepassword=$_POST['databasepassword'];
/* Database connection start */
$servername = $databasehost;
$username = $databaseuser;
$password = $databasepassword;
$dbname = $databasename;

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */

global $wpdb;


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;

//echo $requestData;   

$columns = array(
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0=>'Date',
    1=>'display_name',
    2=> 'LeaveType',
    3 => 'LeaveBalance',
    4 => 'NumberOfDays',
    5 => 'Status',
    6 => 'ID'
 );



// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT leaveassign.FromDate,user.display_name,leaveassign.LeaveType,leaveassign.Status,(leaveentitle.Days-datediff(leaveassign.ToDate, leaveassign.FromDate) ) as LeaveBalance,datediff(leaveassign.ToDate, leaveassign.FromDate) as NumberOfDays,leaveassign.leaveassign.ID ";
$sql.="FROM `wp_ag_assign_leave` as leaveassign INNER join  wp_ag_leave_entitlement as leaveentitle INNER JOIN wp_users as user ON leaveassign.UserId=user.ID";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.//

$sql = "SELECT leaveassign.FromDate,user.display_name,leaveassign.LeaveType,leaveassign.Status,(leaveentitle.Days-datediff(leaveassign.ToDate, leaveassign.FromDate) ) as LeaveBalance,datediff(leaveassign.ToDate, leaveassign.FromDate) as NumberOfDays,leaveassign.leaveassign.ID ";
$sql.="FROM `wp_ag_assign_leave` as leaveassign INNER join  wp_ag_leave_entitlement as leaveentitle INNER JOIN wp_users as user ON leaveassign.UserId=user.ID";
//if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
//  $sql.=" where ( user.display_name LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
//  $sql.=" OR leaveassign.LeaveType LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
//
//  $sql.=" OR leaveassign.Status LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
//        $sql.=" OR LeaveBalance LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
//        
//        
//        $sql.=" OR NumberOfDays LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
//}
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */    
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");




$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array


    $nestedData=array();
        $nestedData[] = $row["FromDate"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["display_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["LeaveType"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["LeaveBalance"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["NumberOfDays"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Status"];

    $nestedData[] = $row["ID"];
    $data[] = $nestedData;


}   


$json_data = array(
                "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),
                "data"            => $data,


                "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
        "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);
?>
```